# Django returns an array instead of a dictionary (rest-api-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I send a post request with data (using `requests.post('url', data=data)` ):

```
data = {
       'token':1234,
       'data':{
             'name':'test',
             'etc':True,
              }
       }
```

When processing `reguest.POST` in django i get:

```
<QueryDict: {'token':[1234], 'data':['name', 'etc']} >
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: It always represents this as a list, since the same key can occur multiple times.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem How to get data values into 'data'?

Comment: these are not send prooperly, since you can not send a dictionary as value, you will need to (JSON) serialize this, and deserialize this at the receiving end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be the reason?

This is simply how a `QuerDict` is represented. This is because in a *querystring* and in a HTTP header, the same key can occur *multiple* times. It thus maps a key to the value.

If you [*subscript* the item [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__), like `request.POST['token']` it will always return the *last* element, if you use [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist), it will return a list of all items:

```
request.POST['token']          # 1234
request.POST.getlist('token')  # ['1234']
```

Furthermore, as you found out, you can not pass a dictionary as value. If you want to send this, you need to serialize it, for example as a string:

```
import json

data = {
    'token':1234,
    'data': json.dumps({
        'name':'test',
        'etc':True,
    })
}
```

then at the receiving end, you can deserialize these:

```
import json

json.loads(request.POST['data'])
```